# What does this code do?

Tags: php

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q='.urlencode(current(explode('(', $ask_key))).'" target="_blank">
```

I can't understand what `urlencode(current(explode('(', $ask_key )))` does.
Can anybody explain me what that code does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$array` is an [**string**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), that must contain several values, separated by `(`.

[**`explode()`**](https://www.php.net/explode) will split this string into an [**array**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), using `(` as a separator.

[**`current()`**](https://www.php.net/current) will get the current element of the array -- the first one.

and, finally, [**`urlencode()`**](https://www.php.net/urlencode) will encode special characters, so they can be used in an URL.

So, basically :

- Take the first element of a string such as `these(are(elements`
- apply the `urlencode` function to it, so it can be used in an URL.

As an example, here is the same kind of code, split into several distinct operations, using a variable to store the result of each function -- so we can dump those results :

```
$string = "th@is?i&s(a couple(of elements";
var_dump($string);

$array = explode('(', $string);
var_dump($array);

$first_item = current($array);
var_dump($first_item);

$encoded = urlencode($first_item);
var_dump($encoded);
```

The four [**`var_dump()`**](https://www.php.net/var_dump) will give this output :

```
string 'th@is?i&s(a couple(of elements' (length=30)

array
  0 => string 'th@is?i&s' (length=9)
  1 => string 'a couple' (length=8)
  2 => string 'of elements' (length=11)

string 'th@is?i&s' (length=9)

string 'th%40is%3Fi%26s' (length=15)
```

Which shows in details what each portion of your expression does.

Comment: Verbosity trumps succinctness yet again :)

Answer (score 3):

[explode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string `$ask_key` into an array using `(` as the delimiter (so if the value of `$ask_key` is `a(b(c`, then `array('a', 'b', 'c')` will be returned.

and grab the first, i.e., [current](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) (as a new array will be pointing to its first element), element of that array

then [urlencode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it (making it safe for use in a query string).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ask_key = 'as das  df(sdfkj as(asf  a152451(sdfa df1 9'; //you key

echo $ask_key."<br/>";

$array = explode('(', $ask_key); //explode will split the array on '('

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";


$curr = current($array); //current will return the curr element of array

echo $curr."<br/>";

$enc = urlencode($curr); //url will encode url i.e. valid url

echo $enc;
```

**Result::**

```
as das df(sdfkj as(asf a152451(sdfa df1 9

Array
(
    [0] => as das  df
    [1] => sdfkj as
    [2] => asf  a152451
    [3] => sdfa df1 9
)

as das df
as+das++df
```